# PHP Search results error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have written the below code as a test , but results are not comng in under the table I have created , the table appear along the top and all the results appear down the left hand side and even if I dont add anythig in the search all teh results show.?, cant see where I am going wrong. I am not worried about the actual HTML Look as it just a test. Appreciate the help. Error is

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="style5.css"/>
</head>
<boby>
    <div class="third_bar"> 
        <div class="second_image"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="form"><form action= "search1.php" method="post"> 
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search_bar" placeholder="" value="Search for your whisky here" max length="30" autocomplete="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive();"/><input type="submit" id="search_button" value="Go!"/> 
            </form>  
        </div> 
</body>
    </div> 

</html>
```

**search1.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['search'])){

    include ('connect.php');


$search = $_POST['search'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM whisky_results";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('error getting data');

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Whisky Name</th> <th>Whisky Desription</th> <th>Highest Price Recorded</th> <th>Lowest Price Recorded</th> </tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td><td>";

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['description'];
    echo "</td><td>";

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['highest_price'];
    echo "</td><td>";

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['lowest_price'];
    echo "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


?>
```

Comment: Well for starters, your form has no input called **submitted**

Comment: Oop , thanks. Have changed it as above and getting a fatal error now.

Comment: Sounds like you might not have mysqli installed. What do you get when you do this:    echo extension_loaded("mysqli")

Comment: The result is 1

Comment: aha! array has two r's.  You only have one. Also, you should check that $result is not FALSE before trying to use it.

Comment: been working on this for ages and eyes are all googleeyy. Thanks. Results are showing now , will need to check about $results being false as fairly new to this. I have updated again as I now get the results but they are not showing under the tables I created. As above ( in a few momwnts)